# Check if all checkboxes are selected

Tags: jquery

How do I check if all checkboxes with `class="abc"` are selected?

I need to check it every time one of them is checked or unchecked. Do I do it on click or change?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

I think the easiest way is checking for this condition:

```
$('.abc:checked').length == $('.abc').length
```

You could do it every time a new checkbox is checked:

```
$(".abc").change(function(){
    if ($('.abc:checked').length == $('.abc').length) {
       //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 115):

```
$('input.abc').not(':checked').length > 0
```

Comment: Perfect, clean and elegant solution. "if ($('input.abc').not(":checked").length) {...}" also works.

Comment: That answer not correct. It checking if there is any checkboxes checked. But question is _Check if **all** checkboxes are selected_. So the correct code is: `$('input.abc').not(':checked').length === 0`.

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer if you consider performance. This will loop just once, instead of twice.

Comment: This approach is cleaner because it does not require knowing the selector used to obtain the original jQuery collection - similarly you can use `$someCollection.is(':checked').length` for other related tests.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576560 for notes about further optimization.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].abc").change(function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].abc");
    if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
        alert('all checked');
    }
});
```

All this will do is verify that the total number of `.abc` checkboxes matches the total number of `.abc:checked`.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/7yQgx/).**

Comment: Not really sure why, but my a.length gives me a value of 8 while I have only 4 checkboxes.

Comment: The `filter` is a good solution for a group of checkboxes, thanks much.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.abc[checked!=true]').length == 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Part 1 of your question:

```
var allChecked = true;
$("input.abc").each(function(index, element){
  if(!element.checked){
    allChecked = false;
    return false;
  } 
});
```

EDIT:

The ([above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541387/check-if-all-checkboxes-are-selected/5541480#5541480)) is probably better.

Comment: This is the most efficient answer, because it short-circuits as soon as an unchecked box is found.  However, you can use `this` rather than `element` to avoid the callback requiring any explicit parameters.

Answer (score 4):

A class independent solution

```
var checkBox = 'input[type="checkbox"]';
if ($(checkBox+':checked').length == $(checkBox).length) {
   //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The search criteria is one of these:

```
input[type=checkbox].MyClass:not(:checked)
input[type=checkbox].MyClass:checked
```

You probably want to connect to the change event.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could have also used every():

```
// Cache DOM Lookup
var abc = $(".abc");

// On Click
abc.on("click",function(){

    // Check if all items in list are selected
    if(abc.toArray().every(areSelected)){
        //do something
    }

    function areSelected(element, index, array){
        return array[index].checked;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved it in my code:

```
if($('.citiescheckbox:checked').length == $('.citiescheckbox').length){
    $('.citycontainer').hide();
}else{
    $('.citycontainer').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it worked well for me.

```
if($('.abc:checked').length < 1) {
  alert('No checkbox is selected.');
  return false;
} else {
  alert($('.abc:checked').length+' checkboxes have been selected')
}
```