# How to check if all of the checkbox are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How can I check if all of my checkboxes are checked or unchecked with jquery,I have child and grandchild input elements-

codepen setup : http://codepen.io/Assert/pen/BLBjpk

```
<ul id="treeList">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> mCRC
  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> STIVARGA Efficacy
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> Long-Term Responders
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> STIVARGA in Clinical Practice
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> STIVARGA AE Management
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> Dosing
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> Patient Communication
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> Case Studies
  </li>
</ul>

<li>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole"> GIST
</li>
```

Comment: `if($('#treelist :checkbox:not(:checked)').length){ // not all are checked}`

Comment: or in other words, count how many checkboxes there are, count how many are checked. if the two numbers don't match ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if all checkboxes are selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541387/check-if-all-checkboxes-are-selected)

Comment: @PranavCBalan  how about, all of them are unchecked ?!!

Comment: @WalidOmonos : avoid the `:not()` ... `$('#treelist :checkbox:checked').length`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **[`:checkbox`](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)** to get all checkbox then use the combination of **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** and **[`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** to filter out all unchecked checkbox.

```
if($('#treeList :checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0){ 
   // all are checked
} else if($('#treeList :checkbox:checked').length == 0){
   // all are unchecked
}
```

---

```js
$('#treeList :checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($('#treeList :checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0) {
    console.log('all are checked');
  } else if ($('#treeList :checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
    console.log('all are unchecked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="treeList">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">mCRC
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">STIVARGA Efficacy
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">Long-Term Responders
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">STIVARGA in Clinical Practice
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">STIVARGA AE Management
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">Dosing
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">Patient Communication
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">Case Studies
      </li>
    </ul>

    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">GIST
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: will the above method work, if I add " checked " in html markup, then uncheck menually from browser ?!!!

Comment: @WalidOmonos : yes

Comment: The second statement is now working, when I uncheck all of the check boxes, the following event does not trigger @Pranav

Comment: @WalidOmonos :  Check the snippet.... both are working for me.... if you were checked all the checkbox then it will show as checked all