# How can I check if all checkboxes have been checked in PHP?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am implementing a list of items and each has a checkbox. I currently can see which checkboxes have been checked but what I want to do is check if all of them have been checked. How can I implement that?

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <?php
                echo "<table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Customer ID</th>
                    <th>Report ID</th>
                    <th>Report message</th>
                    <th>Device</th>
                    <th>Device no.</th>
                    <th>Barcode</th>
                    <th>IMEI</th>
                    <th>Sale-date</th>
                    </tr>";

                while ($row2 = $clientUsername->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $_SESSION['cl_username'] = $row2["username"];
                    while ($row = $message->fetch_assoc()) {

                        $_SESSION['accept'] = $row["acceptance"];
                        $_SESSION['client_comment'] = $row["message"];
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $row["name"];
                        $_SESSION['sales_date'] = $row["sales_date"];
                        $_SESSION['date_sent'] = $row["date_sent"];


                        $_SESSION['countable_array']  = $row;

                        ?>

                <?php if ($row['acceptance'] == 3) {

                            echo "<tr> <td>
                                  " . '<input type=checkbox name=devices[] value=' . $row['dev_id'] . '>' . "
                            </td> <td>" . $cus_id . " </td> <td>" . $rep_id . "</td> <td>" . $_SESSION['client_comment'] . "</td> <td>" . $_SESSION['name'] . "</td> <td>" . $row["device_no"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["barcode"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["serial_imei"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["serial_no"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["sales_date"] . "</td></tr>";
                            echo "</table>";
                        }
                    }
                }
</form>

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['rejected'])) {
 if (count($count_devices) == 1) {
...
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if all checkboxes are selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541387/check-if-all-checkboxes-are-selected)

Comment: `I currently can see which checkboxes have been checked` - where are you doing that in that code? I can't see any form submission and check of the request variables.

Comment: @Nawin this question is not tagged with JavaScript or jQuery... :)

Comment: Did you try to check if $_POST['devices'] is empty?
if (empty($_POST['devices'] ) {
//not all check boxes is check
}

Comment: @ConstantinGroß I just updated my question. I added the other code.

Comment: @Nawin it doesnt really answer my question.

Comment: I dont know who marked this as a duplicate when I have not tagged this question with JavaScript nor jQuery! Stackoverflow used to be better!

Comment: Unless you tell PHP what the available checkboxes are, there's **no** way for it to know whether they're all checked or not - especially considering unchecked boxes aren't even included in the HTTP request.

Comment: @CD001 alright, how can I do that?

Comment: Depends on how strict you want to be (e.g. you *could* whitelist the POST vars in the code) - but it looks like you've got an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    while ($row2 = $clientUsername->fetch_assoc()) {

        $_SESSION['cl_username'] = $row2["username"];

        $i = 0; // initiate the variable here
        $total_number_of_rows = $message->num_rows(); // Get total number of rows from your object
        while ($row = $message->fetch_assoc()) {

            $_SESSION['accept'] = $row["acceptance"];
            $_SESSION['client_comment'] = $row["message"];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $row["name"];
            $_SESSION['sales_date'] = $row["sales_date"];
            $_SESSION['date_sent'] = $row["date_sent"];


            $_SESSION['countable_array']  = $row;

             if ($row['acceptance'] == 3) {
                $i++; // When conditions trues, increment the variable.
                echo "<tr> <td>
                      " . '<input type=checkbox name=devices[] value=' . $row['dev_id'] . '>' . "
                </td> <td>" . $cus_id . " </td> <td>" . $rep_id . "</td> <td>" . $_SESSION['client_comment'] . "</td> <td>" . $_SESSION['name'] . "</td> <td>" . $row["device_no"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["barcode"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["serial_imei"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["serial_no"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["sales_date"] . "</td></tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
        }

        if($i == $total_number_of_rows){ // Here implement this condition, If both equal then all inputs have checked.
            echo "Check box checked all inputs"; 
        }
    } 
?>
```

I think you expecting the same as above. We need to check the Total number of rows with Incremental variable value.

Please review my comment inside the code part, so that you can understand terms.

Comment: I like the approach but num_rows() is not working, it shows an error.

Comment: That you need handle @bmm, You can get the number rows from the Message class

Comment: Message is not a class, its the query fetched from DB.

Comment: Then you can get the total number of rows from that message query @bmm

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()

Comment: Just try with **$message->num_rows**

Comment: thats not a funciton so it should be like this : if ($message->num_rows >0) {...}

Comment: So you got the number of rows from $message->num_rows, Right.

Comment: btw how can you save an array in Session and count the items in it?

Comment: When the condition trues, you can set the session variable  $_SESSION['key_value'][] = $count. Hope this is what you are expecting , If not please explain the thing clearly.

Comment: if I set the $_SESSION['key_value'][]  =  $array_values; and then access it somewhere else, should I just call it like this: $_SESSION['key_value'] ?

Comment: actually its showing an errror saying the array values are not string

Comment: @bmm I don't know, what you wanted to do with the session.! post your exact problem with code.

Comment: nvm that, I am comparing these two if they are the same length like this but doesnt seem to give me a proper return: if ($message->num_rows == $selected_items) {
                echo "The selected number is equal to the fetched devices";
}

Comment: print this **$_SESSION['countable_array']** and post it here Bro.

Comment: $selected_items contains all the selected devices.

Comment: If you don't mind. I don't understand your problem, Sorry. If possible create a new question and post your queries over there.

Comment: How do you set an array in Session? And how would i compare it with the message->num_rows ?

Comment: $selected_items = array('5', '4', '12'); // Countable array

    $_SESSION['countable_array'] = $selected_items;  // Initiate the session here print_r($_SESSION['countable_array'])

  you will get below result

    $_SESSION['countable_array'][0] = 5
    $_SESSION['countable_array'][1] = 4
    $_SESSION['countable_array'][2] = 12

    So you can check the number of rows like this 

    foreach ($_SESSION['countable_array'] as $key => $value) {
        # code...
        if($value == $message->num_rows){
            echo "Condition true, Your code goes here..!";
        }
    }

Comment: Copy and past above comment in you text editor and test the result.

Comment: its not working, it says the length are not the same but in fact they are.